# htaccess rewrite html file to parent directory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, file, directory

I'm trying to create a dynamic pretty url:
`domain.nl/name-of-folder/name-of-file.html`
to
`domain.nl/name-of-folder`

where `name-of-folder` and `name-of-file` are the same

eg.
`/homepage/homepage.html` to `/homepage`

and
`/product/product.html` to `/product`

I've tried a bunch, but I'm not a star when it comes to htaccess and regex.
Can anyone help me out?

*if there's already an existing topic with the solution, I haven't found it yet, but a push in the right direction would be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? You should be able to use the same back reference twice

Comment: eventually managed to do it with
`RewriteRule ^(.*)/ $1/$1.html [L]`